# Change default port number of Sql server 2008 through commad line

Tags: java, sql-server, system-administration

I want to change the default port number 1433 to another in SQL server 2008. Is there any command line option for this? I know that how to change the port number through SQL Server Configuration Manager but I need to change this from my java application.

Any idea about this

Comment: @khan: please do not format non-code as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no command line utility, but you can do it with WMI. There is an MSDN blog about it here: https://serverfault.com/questions/123411/change-port-number-via-command-line-in-sql-server-2005